# Checking a pull request in bash

Tags: git, bash, github, git-branch

Say I have a repo in github, and someone issues a PR. It is there anyway to check if PR is made, and what is the difference with my origin branch using git from terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitHub's pull requests are built on top of Git's native refs system. As outlined in the GitHub help page [checking out pull requests locally](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally), it is possible to `fetch` pull requests to your local machine:

1. Manually modify the `.git/config` file in your repository to add a new `fetch` line to whatever your GitHub remote is called (if you don't know, this is probably `origin`):

   ```
   [remote "origin"]
     url = git@github.com:<USERNAME>/<REPO_NAME>.git
     fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

     # Add this new line:
     fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/pull/origin/*
   ```
2. Now `fetch` from your remote:

   ```
   git fetch origin
   ```
3. Check out a pull request:

   ```
   git checkout pull/origin/123
   ```

This will let you compile / test the pull request and decide if you wish to accept it using GitHub's web UI.

Answer (score 1):

Check the commands `pulls` and `pull-diff` at https://github.com/ingydotnet/git-hub. It makes the GitHub API accessible easily from bash.

Comment: These are not native commands. Do I need to download a plunging for this? Because I get the standard `pulls: command not found`

Comment: @iOi: You have to install the project I linked to.

Comment: I did as the instruction suggested, but I am getting an error. Are you sure this works in Windows

Comment: @iOi: Oh, MS Windows terminal running CMD.EXE? No, you need bash (cygwin maybe).

Comment: Nope. I have gitbash.